# Geometric Sum of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, power-series

Suppose $p(L)$ is a polynomial of negative powers of the lag operator, that is
$$p(L) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_jL^{-j},$$ 
with real coefficients. What assumptions must $\{p_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ satisfy in order for 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty p(L)^i = \frac{1}{1-p(L)}? $$

---

My guess is that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty |p_j|$ must be less than $1$, but I can't quite figure out how to formalize this.

Comment: Note that in general "infinite sums" are called "series" (power series or Laurent series). Only if the coefficient sequence is finite, $p_i=0$ for $i\ge N$ with some integer $N$, you can speak of "polynomials".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need $$\|p(L)\|<1\tag1$$ for the operator series to converge after the theorem for Neumann series (geometric series in powers of some linear operator).

As $\|p(L)\|\le\sum_{i=0}^\infty |p_i|\,\|L^{-i}\|=\sum_{i=0}^\infty |p_i|$, it is sufficient to demand 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty |p_i|<1.\tag2
$$
It is however not necessary, that is, there will be series that satisfy (1) without satisfying (2).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Would you mind explaining why you set $||L^{-i}||=1$?

Comment: I assumed that "lag operator" means a shift operator with unit shift? Then under any translation invariant norm on the sequence space the operator is isometric, thus has operator norm $1$.